# How to get Azure Chat Bot user status on to a dashboard (web application)

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, botframework

We have our users login to MS Teams and interacting with the azure chatbot

We have another admin dashboard UI web application where the admin can view

- which users are currently active online
- view live communications between the user and azure Chat Bot
- if the bot failed to provide an answer to the user, then the admin user should be able to respond to the user's query from the dashboard (human handoff)

Here are my thoughts on the above scenario

Each time a user sends a message to the Chatbot will keep sending "Active" status message to the azure event grid.
if the user is not active for 5 minutes, then another "inactive" status message to event grid

I think I will be able to pull chat messages from the Application Insights. But not sure how I will identify chat messages from a specific user. I think there might be a slight delay in getting logs to appear application insights. Is there a better way to get live chat messages to the admin dashboard?

To get  status messages to the Dashboard web app,  I will set up a Web-Hook based subscriber which will be listening to the event grid

Not sure how the admin will get to know bot's failure to answer and how to send a response to the user's question if needed.

How can I do this? Any pointers to relevant code samples or documents?

Comment: Why use application insights to get the messages. While possible, it would be complicated and, yes, there would be a delay. Why not read the activity as it passes thru the bot and forward it from there?

Comment: There is a C# hand-off [sample](https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample) that you can explore and possibly make use of.